# Express serve static files in nested directory

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, static-files

I am not new to working with express and rendering template views but recently I tried a new directory structure which seems to have confused my app instance.

It no longer serves my `static bootstrap, css and image` files anymore and my view looks all messed up now.

Here's my directory structure

```
AppName
 - node_modules folder
 - src (all code live here)
        - public (statics)
             - css/mycss, bootstrapcss
             - js/ myjs, bootstrapjs
             - images folder
        - models
        - app.js (entry point)
```

The static files seem to be two levels deeper than the root directory. In my `app.js` file, I have tried using `express static method` like so:

```
app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, './src' + '/public')));
```

and also tried this:

```
app.use('/src', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

In my views, for example the statics are called like this:

```
<link href="../public/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/styles.css" type="text/css">

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/1.0.0-alpha.2/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

but still unable to serve those files to my views. I'm stuck on this.
Can someone help me out? Thanks

Comment: try just `app.use(express.static('public'));` in `app.js`

Comment: So, are `mycss` and `bootstrapcss`, etc. files or directories?

Comment: The css and bootstrap are files inside the public folder

Comment: @mmm, it doesn't work

Comment: Have you changed the path for these assets on your views?

Comment: @devius, yes..the statics are referenced using ../public but that doesnt work in app.js

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you post the part of the view code where you're loading your assets?

Comment: @devius, Ok...I'll edit the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/public')));
```

And this:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: No error...just the same plain html or in this case ejs. I have removed all my files from the src folder to the root directory and it worked.