# Express.js not sending css file

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, server

I am setting up a web server with exprss.js and socket.io. I set up a static folder so I can link my stylesheets without having to send every single file. But I am  getting this error

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/styles/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

this is my app.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('chat message', {hello: 'world'});
    socket.on('chat message', function (data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

the index.html page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles/index.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>yo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the file structure is the following

```
|-public
   |-styles
     -index.css
   |-views
     -index.html
-app.js
```

I think there is something wrong with my server setup
This is my first time using node

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express serve static files in nested directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193085/express-serve-static-files-in-nested-directory)

Comment: Remove the `/public` from the `href` atribute so it's `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/index.css">` The `express.static('public')` serves public folder at root `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error usually when there is no CSS file under that link.

When you use `app.use(express.static('public'));` directly express serves everything under root endpoint.

So you can use `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/index.css">`.

If you would like to use `/public/xxx.css` you can use

`app.use('public', express.static('public'));`

Answer (score 0):

When you use static, the original folder is not included in the path url, try something like this :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/index.css">
```